# Union between sets

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am taking a Coursera Functional Programming in Scala class. This is the second week and I hit a wall. In the assignment we are working with Sets, but not the kind of Set we all meet in Java, for example. It is a Set that returns true if the value is in there and false otherwise. They say it's not a container, it's just a function.

To get it clear, I need your help. I don't want you to solve my assignment, it's just an example that I want to get the idea of what I should do.

```
/**
   * We represent a set by its characteristic function, i.e.
   * its `contains` predicate.
   */
  type Set = Int => Boolean

 /**
   * Indicates whether a set contains a given element.
   */
  def contains(s: Set, elem: Int): Boolean = s(elem)

 /**
   * Returns the set of the one given element.
   */
  def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set = Set(elem)

 /**
   * Returns the union of the two given sets,
   * the sets of all elements that are in either `s` or `t`.
   */
  def union(s: Set, t: Set): Set = ???
```

This is the code. In the `singletonSet` I guess the way to solve it is to return the `Set(elem)`, right?

If that is good, how am I supposed to make the union between the two? I am not new to programming but I can't see any way to do it. Since I shouldn't return a "set" of numbers.

This is what another student told me about sets: "*But all a "Set" is is a function that takes an Int and returns a Boolean (Int => Boolean). Any function that takes an Int and returns a Boolean fits the type 'Set'.*"

What I tried in the union function is to have something like:

```
def union(s: Set, t: Set): Set = (s | t) //value | not a member of Int => Boolean
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Curious that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052735/is-my-understanding-of-below-scala-code-correct is essentially the same question and it remains open. IMO both should be open as they are valid questions.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It seems the wall you are hitting is that you are unfamiliar with defining functions in Scala. In this particular case you need to define functions of type `Int => Boolean`, they take an `Int` and return a `Boolean`.

Here are some examples of function literals of type `Int => Boolean`. Try them in the Scala console or the Scala IDE worksheet:

```
(x: Int) => true
(x: Int) => false
(x: Int) => x == 2
(x: Int) => x == 10
(x: Int) => x == 2 || x == 10
(x: Int) => x % 2 == 0
```

Then all you have to do for the assignment is to use the same syntax, starting with `(x: Int) =>` and then translate the meaning of union, intersect, ... into the right hand side of the expression.

Part of learning is giving it a genuine effort. I believe you can resubmit the solution multiple times, so don't hesitate to submit and iterate if you don't get 10/10 on the first try. All you need is compiling code. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

A possible hint is to look at the types. Look at the `Set` type. It is actually a type alias to a function from `Int` into `Boolean`.

Thus, when you have two sets, you actually have two functions. How can you use them to provide a function that represent the union of these Set? It must be your starting point.

Comment: I would do an OR between the two functions, but I'd also need an X. I can't get to a better answer.

Comment: You forgot the more important fact: `Set` is an alias for a function. Your `X` come from it: you must return a function, that explains what to do with an "external" `X`.

Comment: so it is an OR between the 2 sets? I tried this and it doesn't work to have "s | t", it says "value | is not a member of Int => Boolean".

Comment: You have two function `Int => Boolean` and your result is Int => Boolean, you must therefore build your own function from the two initial ones: x => `f(x) || g(x)`