# Is my understanding of below scala code correct?

Tags: scala

I'm just trying to understand the below code :

---

Here a new type alias Set is declared which is a function that takes an Int
parameter and returns a boolean

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
```

---

Here a new method 'contains' is declared, which takes two parameters of type Set and Int
which returns a boolean. The boolean is set to the function declared in earlier 
('type Set = Int => Boolean')
But what logic is performed to determine if the Int 'elem' is a member of Set 's'

```
def contains(set: Set, elem: Int): Boolean = set(elem)
```

---

Here a method is defined which returns a set which returns a function ?

```
def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set = set => set == elem
```

---

Complete code with comments :

```
  /**
   * We represent a set by its characteristic function, i.e.
   * its `contains` predicate.
   */
  type Set = Int => Boolean

      /**
       * Indicates whether a set contains a given element.
       */
def contains(set: Set, elem: Int): Boolean = set(elem)

      /**
       * Returns the set of the one given element.
       */
      def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set = set => set == elem
```

Comment: You're asking for the answer to the coursera Scala course assignment 2.

Comment: I believe he just asked for explanation. In fact, I'm taking this course right now and functional programming is totaly new for me. I also have the problem with this assingment... I don't want solution - just explanation. And Paola below gave just what I needed.

Comment: I, too, intuited how to write this (eventually) but benefited from Paolo's answer.  Not everyone who comes here is trying to cheat.  Thanks Moby for defending the fine point of how this question was asked. +1

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Let's read sort of backwards, in logical order.

Say you have a finite set of integers: `0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8` for instance

One way to describe this set of integers is through a function (its [characteristic or indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)) that, for each integer, returns true if the integer is in the set, false if it is not.
The signature for this function, as we described it, must always be `Int => Boolean` ("give me an integer, I will tell you if it's in the set"), while its implementation will vary depending on the specific set.

For the set in my example above you could write this function simply as:

```
val mySet: Int => Boolean = x => Array(0,1,2,3,5,8) contains x
```

or recognize that the ints in the set are the first ones of the Fibonacci sequence and define f in a slightly more sophisticated way (which I won't do here...).
Note that the "contains" I've used is defined for all scala collections.
In any case, now you have a function that tells you what is in the set and what is not.
Let's try it in the REPL.

```
scala> val mySet: Int => Boolean = x => Array(0,1,2,3,5,8) contains x
mySet: Int => Boolean = <function1>

scala> mySet(3)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> mySet(9)
res1: Boolean = false
```

Now, mySet has type `Int => Boolean`, which we can make more readable if we define it as a type alias.

```
scala> type Set = Int => Boolean
defined type alias Set
```

Besides readability, defining `Set` as an alias of `Int => Boolean` is making it explicit that in a way a Set **is** its characteristic function. We can redefine mySet in a more concise (but otherwise equivalent) way with the `Set` type alias:

```
scala> val mySet: Set = x => Array(0,1,2,3,5,8) contains x
mySet: Int => Boolean = <function1>
```

Now for the last piece of this long answer. Let's define a characteristic function to describe this Singleton set: `3`.
Easy:

```
val Singleton3 : Set = set => set == 3
```

for a Singleton set containing only 4, it would be:

```
val Singleton4 : Set = set => set == 4
```

So, let's generalize the creation of these functions and write a method that returns a Singleton function that, for any integer, describes the set containing only that integer:

```
def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set = set => set == elem
```

---

**APPENDIX:**

I skipped this part, because it wasn't really needed: `def contains(set: Set, elem: Int): Boolean = set(elem)`

I think it's sort of pointless and (without more context) it looks just like a contrived example to demonstrate how you can pass a function around as an argument, just like any other type in scala. It takes the `Int => Bool` function and the `Int` and just applies the function to the `Int` so you can do

```
scala> contains(mySet, 3)
res2: Boolean = true
```

which is like calling `mySet(3)` directly.

Comment: I agree with your Appendix: This is basically the Church Encoding of Sets in the Lambda Calculus (which surprisingly is also the Object-Oriented Encoding – see [*On Understanding Data Abstraction, Revisited*](http://CS.UTexas.Edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf) by [William R. Cook](http://WCook.BlogSpot.Com/) to understand why). The neat trick is precisely that the set is at the same time the object and the characteristic function and this `contains` method needlessly obscures that beautiful design.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella What is the verbose way for "val Singleton4 : Set = set => set == 4" I am unable to understand where the "set" parameter is coming from

Comment: @Pangea `set => set == 4` is a closure, that takes an input called `set` and returns a boolean output (is `set` == 4?). You can use `x` or any other name instead of `set`. Here, we're taking the whole closure and assigning it to a val called `Singleton4`. Hope it's clearer now

Comment: The method singletonSet returns a set, where as the closure returns a boolean. I'm confused.

Comment: @VanchinathanChandrasekaran `singletonSet` returns a `Set`. A `Set` is an alias for an `Int => Boolean` closure. So it's correct for the closure to return a `Boolean`. Or am I misunderstanding the cause of your confusion?

Comment: @PaoloFalabella So 'Set' in this instance is not a data structure, but rules implemented as functions that are true to Set logic.  Is that fair to say?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I more thing for me to understand, where does it store the numbers when you do a val s1 = singletonSet(1), is there a structure behind it? I come from imperative programming and this baffles me. Thanks!

Comment: @user1434770 Hard to reply in a non-confusing way in a comment but basically yes... singletonSet(1) returns a function, and a function is represented like an object in scala, with its own internal state stored on the heap,

Answer (score 5):

After watching the lecture video on "Currying", I believe that Paolo's solution expressed in a more verbose manner is :

```
    def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set = {
    def innerFunction (givenElement: Int) = 
      if (elem == givenElement) true
      else false
      innerFunction
  }
```

Plesae correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: This is a lot shorter using an anonymous function: `def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set = (x: Int) => elem == x`

Comment: The method singletonSet returns a set, where as the closure returns a boolean. I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question - *But what logic is performed to determine if the Int 'elem' is a member of Set 's'*

This is performed when you make the actual function call. Consider the following function call.

> contains(singletonSet(1), 1)

Now singletonSet is defined as **def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set = x => x == elem** (I choose to use the identifier x for clarity sake). The return type of the singletonSet is the function of type Set which takes an Int argument and returns Boolean. So the above calling function's first argument singletonSet(1) equates to the function **x => x == 1** as elem here is 1. So we get

> contains((x => x == 1),1)

Now considering the definition of contains function **def contains(f: Set, elem: Int): Boolean = f(elem)**. The first argument in the call above is the function x => x == 1 which substitutes formal parameter f and second argument 1 substitutes formal parameter elem. The return value of contains is the function f(elem) which equates to f(1). Since f(x) is defined as (x == 1), f(1) equates to (1 == 1) which returns true.

Going by the same logic, a function call like contains(singletonSet(1), 2) would finally equate to (1 == 2) which will return false.

Comment: Ramya, how would that work for the following scenario?

def contains(s: Set, elem: Int): Boolean = s(elem) ; 

val set:Set = Set(1,2,3,4) ; 

contains(set,5) ; 

In this case, I have created a set of more than 1 values. And this is working perfectly fine. Is it iterating for all the values one by one?

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking the course now, was also confused, but I think I get the point now.

`def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set = (x : Int) => x == elem`

here singletonSet is **a function that returns a function with the type Set**, which is defined as `type Set = Int => Boolean`

so when you call `def contains(s:Set, elem:Int): Boolean = s(elem)`, for example: `contains(singletonSet(1), 2)`, singletonSet(1) is returning a function with elem(in the definition of singletonSet) set to 1, and the 2(also defined as elem, but is defined in the parameter of contains) is passed in as the x in singletonSet definition, we need to get rid of java set idea, we don't need the singletonSet to persist the value we set.

For better understanding, we can change the parameter name as following:

`def singletonSet(elemToStore: Int): Set = (x : Int) => x == elemToStore`

`def contains(s: Set, elemToCheck: Int): Boolean = s(elemToCheck)`